# Cocoapod spec file creates extra folders

Tags: ios, cocoapods, specifications

I created new cocoapod project by using pod lib create, changed folder name, edited spec file and updated example project.

In the screenshot you can see that the extra folders have been created. What is my mistake and how to correct it?

Thanks a lot...

Screenshot: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7072397/12080819/b191e36c-b278-11e5-8bda-9569795d536b.png

Answer (score 0):

You are not making any mistake, but .podspec file is meta data file for Pod.

A specification describes a version of Pod library. It includes details about where the source should be fetched from, what files to use, the build settings to apply, and other general metadata such as its name, version, and description.

You can get more detail about Pod Specification file from [Cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html) site.

Comment: Do you now how to remove this folder?

Comment: You can not delete .podspec file, you can go in detail for this on this link :https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html

Comment: I don't need to delete spec file. On screenshot you can see, that each module creates a folder in which files are placed

Comment: Which folder you  want to remove ?

Comment: IGKit folders in each module